# Using reCAPTCHA on localhost with a fake development domain

Tags: recaptcha

I'm currently using a fake development domain instead of `localhost` on my local machine, as I have multiple websites that I want to manage locally.

Google reCAPTCHA is not recognising my domains, and is giving me this error: `ERROR: Invalid domain for site key`

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the fake domain as an entry in your reCAPTCHA whitelist. This can be found in the [reCAPTCHA admin panel](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) for the current reCAPTCHA you are using.

For example, if your fake development domain is `mysite.myfakedomain` you would add `mysite.myfakedomain` to the whitelist.

**Note: The changes may take a few minutes to take place.**